# How to replicate the data from postgresql to graphdb?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j, graph-databases

I have deployed the Neo4j server on the AWS EC2 Ubuntu server instance. I have a certain amount of data on the AWS RDS Postgresql database which I would like to replicate on the graph DB used by the Neo4j application. My question is "Is there any way that U can replicate the data from my AWS Postgresql database onto my graph database?". Any help would be appreciated on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Neo4j-ETL tool, it helps you to map your data-model from PostgreSQL DB to neo4j 
https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-etl/